# Pass list in command line argument in hive

Tags: list, hive, command-line-arguments, where-in

Basically I want to automate hive query based job. Which will take list as input from the file and query will generate reports by applying filters using this input. The input is a list which I want to pass as "where-in" condition in hive query. My query looks like,

// temp.sql //
INSERT INTO TABLE Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2 where pixel_id in ($PIXEL);

I am trying to pass input in command line like this,
hive -f temp.sql -d PIXEL= '('608207','608206','608205','608204','608203','608201','608184','608198','608189')' > temp.log 2>&1 &

I am not sure this is correct way or not?

Anyone has some idea to work around this problem?

Please suggest me some way to work around.

Answer (score 0):

If pixel_id is number, you can use this simple script:

1. Create shell script script.sh with `hive -e "select * from orders where order_id in (${1})"`
2. Save it and change permissions by running chmod +x script.sh
3. Run shell script by passing the values as parameter for example ./script.sh "1, 2, 3, 4"

You can do it for string columns by escaping " like this "\"1\", \"2\""

Answer (score 0):

Try passing like a string with ',' separated list-

run this on bash: `hive -hiveconf myargs="1','2','3','4"`

considering your script looks like this: `SELECT * from mytable where my_id in ('${hiveconf:myargs}');`

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24066224).